# apt and apt-get cause pi to crash

Tags: pi-zero-w, software-installation, apt

I'm running into quite a frustrating problem with my Raspberry Pi Zero W.
When I try to run apt or apt-get, having done nothing on the installation aside from modifying wpa_supplicant and changing the default hostname and password, the Pi will crash at some point during the installation. It doesn't kick me from the SSH session, my terminal will just freeze and the Pi will become unresponsive to ping. The only way to fix it is to remove power and plug it in again.

It doesn't matter whether it's `apt-get update` or `apt install`, whether it's a big package or just a couple megabytes. Every time I run this command the pi crashes.

I have tried fresh installs of RaspOS on different SD Cards, older versions of RaspOS, the desktop and lite versions, but the problem persists no matter what. I've been using this pi for about a year or so now and I've never run into this sort of issue before.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It's driving me nuts!

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        15G  1.7G   12G  13% /
devtmpfs        183M     0  183M   0% /dev
tmpfs           216M     0  216M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           216M  3.1M  213M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           216M     0  216M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   48M  205M  19% /boot
tmpfs            44M     0   44M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: `my terminal will just freeze` cool, is there an error message? perhaps run a second SSH and monitor the logs and you may catch something there - too bad you can't connect it to a TV though ... out of interest, what's the output of `df -h` before you do anything with apt

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had a peek at the logs while trying to install a random package, but there was nothing in there to clue me in to what might be going on. I updated my post with the output of `df -h` but everything seems to be alright there as well :/

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly same issue and after spending days I found out that it has something to do with  ipv6. so if you disable ipv6 or force apt to use ipv4 it will work just fine .

Comment: I never would've thought this had anything to do with it, but wow! This fixed it. I disabled it using these instructions. Thank you!! https://cwesystems.com/?p=231

Answer (score 1):

Run `apt-get -y install mc > log.txt` (or a package of your choice) to collect the actual error message. If the log turns out to be empty or incomplete, try using `unbuffer` or `stdbuf -oL -eL` to disable IO buffering for `apt-get`, so that it flushes `STDOUT` to disk after every line.

Also try downloading a package (e.g.  `wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mc/mc_4.8.26-1_armhf.deb`) and installing the package with `dpkg` to see if the crash is `apt`-related or `dpkg`-related.

Crashes with `apt` / `dpkg` are usually due to filesystem corruption, and the best fix often consists in running `fsck` and reinstalling the system if that didn't help.

Comment: Okay thanks, I tried piping the output into a log file but, as you said, upon rebooting the pi it turned out to be empty. So I then tried using `stdbuf` but that also proved unsuccessful. I was able to manually install some packages using `dpkg` however, so it seems the issue is with `apt`.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but given that I have installed multiple versions of raspbian on multiple SD cards, is it really likely to be filesystem corruption?

Comment: @bobbutnotbob Filesystem corruption has nothing to do with how careful you are when installing. It usually happens when the system crashes or powers down at the wrong moment. Also, if you run `apt` via SSH, you should bear in mind that it can be sporadically killed when the network disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n
```

If you find any packages using high space , type

```
sudo apt-get purge -y (packagename)
```

packagename is the name of the package .